# Rolling logback logs on filesize and time

Tags: java, logging, logback

I've been trying to set up a simple logback project to roll my log files by date and by filesize, and so far I have been unable to get my appender to roll over to another file. Instead, it writes to the log specified by the `<file/>` tag.

Here is my `logback.xml` configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds">
    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="milliroller" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>log/output.log</file>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>log/mylog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.txt</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>1KB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
        <appender-ref ref="milliroller"/>
    </root>

    <logger name="com.tkassembled.logback" level="DEBUG"/>
</configuration>
```

At first glance, it looks like it should work, right? Is there something I'm doing wrong? My entire, buildable project is available in a zip here: http://www.mediafire.com/file/2bxokkdyz2i/logback.zip

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Although this is an old question, I felt that a working answer is appropriate to help anyone who requires this kind of implementation.

I use the following logback configuration to provide an HTML log, rolled over by date and filesize, as well as logging to console for debugging output.

Logfiles are stored in a `logs` directory with a name of `logFile.html` while its active, and `logFile.2013-mm-dd.i.html` when it rolls over, where i is the number of 50MB log files. For instance `logFile.2013-01-07.0.html`.

```xml
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %highlight(%-5level) %cyan(%logger{35}) - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs\logFile.html</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- daily rollover -->
      <fileNamePattern>logs\logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.html</fileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
          <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 50MB -->
        <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
      <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
      <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
      <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout">
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}%thread%level%logger%line%msg</pattern>
      </layout>         
    </encoder>
  </appender> 

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />     
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: See [AndreLDM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36707798/384674), this configuration logs `SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP is deprecated.` with `debug=true` option in `logback.xml`

Comment: According to my test `maxHistory` is not number of days, but number of files, so if you have more files per day, you will have less days...

Comment: Ok, I tested more and it seems like number of periods, which for `yyyy-MM-dd` is number of days, for `yyyy-MM-dd-HH` it is number of hours and works ok with several files in period.

Answer (score 75):

Since logback 1.1.7 (released March 2016) a new policy called `SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy` is available that dramatically simplifies what you need to do:

```xml
<appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>app.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>    
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

See [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy) for further info.

Comment: According to my test `maxHistory` is not number of days, but number of files, so if you have more files per day, you will have less days...

Comment: Unless it's a bug, the [documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy) is clear about `maxHistory` being the number of days (notice the xml comment).

Comment: Not really, [documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#tbrpMaxHistory) reads "The optional maxHistory property controls the maximum number of archive files to keep...", their example of monthly rollover is a bit confusing and comment in XML is really wrong. I'll drop them an e-mail and I'll let you know.

Comment: Ok, I tested more and it seems like number of periods, which for `yyyy-MM-dd` is number of days, for `yyyy-MM-dd-HH` it is number of hours and works ok with several files in period.

Comment: unfortunately for 1.2.12 is buggy - generates .tmp files instead of .gz and never clean up them