# Stop logging if file size is larger than X mb

Tags: java, logging, logback

We've got heavy loaded system. If something doesn't work system generates MB of logs every minute. In a few minutes we already don't have source of the problem (because log files are limited by size)

Is it possible to stop logging if file size is larger than X mb? Does logback have this appender?

Comment: stop logging entirely, as in "logfile full, I will no longer output log messages at all"? Why would anyone want that? And why don't you just roll on file size or date?

Answer (score 1):

This post [Rolling logback logs on filesize and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602415/rolling-logback-logs-on-filesize-and-time) might answer your question :

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logFile.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
         <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 50MB -->
            <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
  <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
</encoder>
</appender>
```

[More infos](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender)

Comment: @fedor.belov wait, what? You want both the new logs and the old logs but don't have room for all the logs?

Answer (score 0):

The full solution would be to use a powerful logging endpoint that aggregates data for you. Logback is stateless and is not powerful enough to do this. [logstash](http://logstash.net/) and [loggly](http://loggly.com) are two such services but there are many.