# spring-boot logback file rotation, cannot get it to rotate log file

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot, logback

Here is my logback.xml in the root of the classpath in my spring-boot application.

When start my application, this file is never rotated, the log file grows and grows into infinity. (well over 100kb with zero rotation, or info in console log of any errors). Directory is writable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

<logger name="com.mystuff" level="DEBUG"/>

<appender name="FILE"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <file>/tmp/mylog.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>/tmp/mylog.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss}.%i</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <MaxFileSize>100KB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
</appender>


<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with included base.xml file. Appender ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender is already defined inside this file. It has set triggeringPolicy to 10MB.

Comment: Even if I define my own file (complete copy of base.xml) and no longer include it, and change it to 10kb, it does not work.

Comment: You cannot use {yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss} pattern in FixedWindowRollingPolicy. Try with `<fileNamePattern>/tmp/mylog.%i.log</fileNamePattern>`.
 [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602415/rolling-logback-logs-on-filesize-and-time) is example how to use date pattern in name of your log file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately "ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy" doesn't process "%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss}" pattern. You have to use only "%i" pattern. "mylog.log.%i" will work well. But if you want to have timestamp in the file name use following:

```
<timestamp key="ts" datePattern="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"/>
```

...

```
<fileNamePattern>mylog.log-${ts}.%i</fileNamePattern>
```