# Configuring logback TimeBasedRollingPolicy to roll a file in specific way

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'm trying to achieve a certain way of rolling files by using `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` but I can't get it to work as I intended.

My current `logback.xml` configuration (logback version 1.1.3):

```
<configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/server.log</file>
        <append>true</append>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/server.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <MaxHistory>7</MaxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <Pattern>[%d] [%thread] [%-5level] [%logger{52}]%n %msg%n%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="TRACE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

---

**How I want the logger to behave**:

- append log to `/logs/server.log` file until it achieves 5MB filesize or the date rolls
- when the `/logs/server.log` file reaches 5MB (or the date rolls)

  - change its name according to `fileNamePattern`(e.g. `logs/server.2016-09-19T10-58.0.log`)
  - create new server.log file to append fresh logs to

---

**How it behaves with mentioned configuration**:

- appends log to `/logs/server.log` file indefinitely, doesn't roll the file at all.

---

**What I've tried so far**:

- removing the main file attribute `<file>${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/server.log</file>`
- using simply the `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` **without** `SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP` and setting the rollover period to one minute (by adding `HH-mm` to `fileNamePattern`)

  These solutions seem to enable file rolling, but unfortunately cause the `/logs/server.log` file to be completely omitted from logging.
- using `FixedWindowRollingPolicy` with filesize-based only `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy` (using the same `fileNamePattern`)

  It causes the logger to append to `/logs/server.log` file indefinitely.

Comment: probably duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602415/rolling-logback-logs-on-filesize-and-time

Comment: The answers provided in the question you've referred to are not solving my problem, as the first configuration I've mentioned is almost identical, (except the size/time parameter values) to the answer provided by your link.