# RollingFileAppender is not working when file reaches max size

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm trying to implement the RollingFileAppender to limit the size of the log

So, here is the implementation in logback.xml :

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <prudent>true</prudent>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover. Make sure the path matches the one in the file element or else
             the rollover logs are placed in the working directory. -->
            <fileNamePattern>${catalina.home}/logs/MARQUEOServices.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>

            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>1MO</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>

        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

when I run the app, the size of the log file isn't limited, it increases only

maybe I've forgotten another parameter?

Comment: That class seems to be deprecated, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36707798/14955 for a replacement. And is `1MO` a supported file size? Does `1MB` work?

Comment: Thank u , it works by changing 1 MO to 1MB