# How to run java jar file on AWS EC2 server

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, pm2, nohup

How to ran Java Jar file in AWS EC2 server.

I have tried -

```
nohup java -jar myfilename.jar > output.log &
```

With the above approach, I will store the logs in output.log file. I want to rotate it after 150 MB completed, Without stopping the application.

Also tried using PM2 -

Create process.json

```
{
    "apps":[
    {
        "name": "my-backend-api",
        "cwd":".",
        "script":"/usr/bin/java",
        "args":[
            "-jar",
            "/home/ubuntu/my-backend/target/my-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
        ],
        "watch":[
            "/home/ubuntu/my-backend/target/my-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
        ],
        "node_args":[],
        "log_date_format":"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
        "exec_interpreter":"",
        "exec_mode":"fork"
     }
   ]
}
```

**pm2 start process.json**

Does not seems to be working, each and every time, its restart the application. I don't want to do that.

Any help here ? Would be appreciated. Thank you in advanced

Comment: PM2 is for javascript, not java.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2602415/1032785

Answer (score 0):

We can ran our application -

```
nohup java -jar ./mybackend-api/target/myapp-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar > ./logs/mylogs.log &
```

**Install Logrotate - (For Ubuntu >= 18.0 version)**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install logrotate

logrotate --version
```

**Rotate Logs -**
https://crontab.guru/

5 * * * * // Every 5 minutes

/home/ubuntu/logs/*.log {
missingok
maxsize 5M
rotate 2
compress
copytruncate
}

**Run Cron Job -**

```
crontab -e
```

Change in the file for every 5 minutes to change the logs
-> `5 * * * * logrotate -f logrotate.conf`

**Restart CRON -**

```
sudo service cron reload
```

Or

```
/etc/init.d/cron reload
```

This is for rotating logs, if you wanted to do so.